# Electron Dialog send file to server with vue resource

Tags: javascript, file, vue.js, electron, vue-resource

I am building an electron app which handles file uploads, I am using dialog to get the files from user, I need to send the files to server but I am getting the files path but I get errors when sending them . I am using Vue resource for requests. Below is my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
  <button @click="uploadAct()"  class="primary">New Upload </button>  
 </div>
</template>
<script>
const {dialog} = require('electron').remote
const fs = require('fs')
import reqApi from '../../api/something'
export default {
 methods: {
   uploadAct () {
     dialog.showOpenDialog({
        title: 'Upload Attachments',
        buttonLabel: 'Upload',
        filters: [
          {name: 'Images', extensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif']},
          {name: 'All Files', extensions: ['*']}
        ],
        properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections']
      }, function (filenames) {
        if (filenames) {
           let d = ''
          filenames.forEach(function (element) {
            d = element
          })
         // here i get a path of file correctly something like /path/to/file.jpg

          reqApi.uploadattachmnets({photo: fs.createReadStream(d)}).then(
              (response) => {
                console.log(response)
              },
              (error) => {
                console.log(error)
              })
           //  })

        }
      })
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

I however end up with error on the request , any help will be appreciated .

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @saurabh am getting error from server side that the file is not sent , have debuged with postman and serverside code is fine , so frontend code is the one not sending the file

Answer (score 0):

Probably a typo but you have a call to an API:

```
carApi.uploadattachmnets({photo: fs.createReadStream(d)})
```

which is different to the one you are importing:

```
import reqApi from '../../api/something'
```

If not the above I'd assume this is going to be a CORS issue if Postman is already able to send files and receive the correct response from the endpoint. Without more info I'd recommend looking at: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-making-a-cors-request

For a more specific response you'd need to post the API code so we can review how you are sending the file.